# Scala: How to convert tuple elements to lists

Tags: scala, tuples, higher-order-functions

Suppose I have the following list of tuples:

```
val tuples = listOfStrings.map(string => {
            val split = string.split(":")
            (split(0), split(1), split(2))
        })
```

I would like to get the split(0) in a list, split(1) in another list and so on.
A simple way this could be achieved is by writing:

```
list1 = tuples.map(x => x._1).toList
list2 = tuples.map(x => x._2).toList
list3 = tuples.map(x => x._3).toList
```

Is there a more elegant (functional) way of achieving the above without writing 3 separate statements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will give you your result as a list of list:

```
tuples.map{t => List(t._1, t._2, t._3)}.transpose
```

If you want to store them in local variables, just do:

```
val List(l1,l2,l3) = tuples.map{t => List(t._1, t._2, t._3)}.transpose
```

**UPDATE**: As pointed by Blaisorblade, the standard library actually has a built-in method for this: `unzip3`, which is just like `unzip` but for triples instead of pairs:

```
val (l1, l2, l3) = tuples.unzip3
```

Needless to say, you should favor this method over my hand-rolled solution above (but for tuples of arity > 3, this would still still apply).

Comment: too slow :)
was about to post: `tuples.map{t => t._1 :: t._2 :: t._3 :: Nil}.transpose` nice one. +1

Comment: Bad idea, you should use unzip from the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17281359/53974

Comment: @Balisorblade: I have to disagree. This would be true if it was a `Tuple2`, but it is a `Tuple3`. `unzip` only handles unzipping pairs, and jeshan's own example show a List of `Tuple3`, not `Tuple2`.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles: So you need unzip3. It's indeed a pity (or a bug) that only pairs and triples are supported — shapeless supports that, but for HList (http://docs.typelevel.org/api/shapeless/stable/1.2.4/doc_2.10/index.html#shapeless.HListOps).

Comment: Also, you can convert a tuple to a list (of Any) with `tuple.productIterator.toList`. So: `def unzip(l: List[Product]) = (l map (_.productIterator.toList)).transpose`

Comment: Yes, but (as already mentioned) with ’productIterator' you'll have to add a cast. Good cacth for `unzip3` though, I did not know it existed in the standard library.

Answer (score 11):

You want unzip:

```
scala> val (numbers, homonyms) = List(("one", "won"), ("two", "too")).unzip
numbers: List[java.lang.String] = List(one, two)
homonyms: List[java.lang.String] = List(won, too)
```

Comment: This only works on pairs though, not on any other kind of tuple

Comment: There's unzip3 for triples.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that can be used for arbitrary tuple sizes:

```
val tupleSize = 3
0.until(tupleSize).toList
    .map(x => (_:Product).productElement(x).asInstanceOf[String])
    .map(tuples.map(_))
```

Obviously, this could be expressed more elegantly if you had a List of Arrays instead.

Comment: Or simply: `tuples.map(_.productIterator.toList).transpose.asInstanceOf[List[List[String]]`. I was going to post this solution, but the cast is a pity.

Comment: I thought about that solution too, but this version is probably more efficient than transpose. The cast can be avoided if we take a `List` of `Array`s as input.

Comment: @jeshan: the solutions that do use _1, _2, _3 have the advantage of being correctly typed without a runtime cast. When using productIterator or produxtElement as above, what you get back is typed as `Any`, hence the need for a cast.

Comment: The real solution is to use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) of course.

Comment: Real solution is to not use tuples

Answer (score 1):

You could just write the statements in a single line.

Like

```
 (list1, list2, list3) = tuples.foldRight((List[String](), List[String](), List[String]()))( (a,b) => (a._1 :: b._1, a._2 :: b._2, a._3 :: b._3 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about elegant but you *could* do it in one line without the intermediate step of storing the tuples. Perhaps it's a little hard to read...

```
(for(split <- listOfStrings.map(_.split(":")))
  yield List(split(0), split(1), split(2))).transpose
```

repl example:

```
scala> listOfStrings
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(a:b:c, d:e:f, g:h:i)

scala> (for(split <- listOfStrings.map(_.split(":")))
     |   yield List(split(0), split(1), split(2))).transpose
res2: List[List[java.lang.String]] = List(List(a, d, g), List(b, e, h), List(c, f, i))
```