# Idiomatic way of extracting lists from a list of tuples

Tags: scala, tuples

Is there a concise way of performing the following mapping in Scala?

```
val listOfTuples: List[Tuple2[Foo, Bar]] = ???
val (foos, bars) = listOfTuples // foo:List[Foo], bar:List[Bar]
```

I have seen [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392409/scala-how-to-convert-tuple-elements-to-lists) `map` the `List[Tuple[X, X]]` onto a `List[List[X]]` and then `transpose` the list, although this only works with tuples composed from homogeneous type parameters.

Comment: This is the answer you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17281359/406435

Comment: I have actually linked to this in the question, although I didn't read down far enough to find *that* answer, which is indeed what I want (not map & transpose like the most voted answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use method `unzip` like this:

```
val (foos, bars) = listOfTuples.unzip
```

There is also a method `unzip3` for collections of `Tuple3`.

Comment: Brilliant, and sorry for not reading the List spec thoroughly enough to find it :(

Answer (score 0):

And if for arity 3 to 22 you could do this with [product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections):

```
 val foos = listOfTuples._1
 val bars = listOfTuples._2
```