# How to loop through tuple in scala

Tags: scala, loops

I have a tuple in scala

```
val captainStuff = ("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")
```

How i can iterate through for loop?? It's easy to loop through list and map. But how to loop through Tuple.

Thanks!!

Comment: Tuples can be iterated over (see `productIterator`) but it is a _bad_ idea. You loose type safety because all the elements become type `Any`.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to "loop" over a tuple, then probably you should consider other data structure, like a sequence .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert it to iterator like:

```
val captainStuff = ("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")

captainStuff.productIterator.foreach(x => {
  println(x)
})
```

This question is a duplicate btw:

[Scala: How to convert tuple elements to lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392409/scala-how-to-convert-tuple-elements-to-lists)

Answer (score 2):

> How i can iterate through for loop?? It's easy to loop through list and map. But how to loop through Tuple.

Lists and maps are collections. Tuples are not. Iterating (aka "looping through") really only makes sense for collections which tuples aren't.

Tuples are product types. They are a way of grouping multiple values **of different types** together into a single structure. Considering that the fields of a tuple may have different types, *how* exactly would you iterate over it? What would be the type of your element variable?

If you are familiar with other languages, you may be familiar with the concept of *records* (e.g. `RECORD` in Pascal or `struct` in C). Tuples are kind of like them, except the fields don't have names. How do you iterate over a record in Pascal or a struct in C? You don't, it makes no sense.

In fact, you can think of an *object* as a record. Again, how do you iterate over the fields of an object? You don't, it makes no sense.

Note #1: Yes, sometimes, it *does* make sense to iterate over the field of an object *iff* you are doing reflective metaprogramming.

Note #2: In Scala, tuples inherit from `Product`, which has a non-typesafe `productIterator` method that gives you an `Iterator[Any]` which allows you to iterate over a tuple, but without type-safety. Just don't do it.

**tl;dr**: tuples are not collections. You simply don't iterate over them. Period. If you think you have to, you're doing something wrong, i.e. you shouldn't have a tuple but maybe an array or a list instead.

Comment: Hi Jörg W Mittag, Thank you for the nice explanation. I have worked in SQL, ETL but i am new to the programming.

Comment: Well, if you know SQL, then you should be set: SQL is all about (sets of) tuples. You "iterate" (actually, you don't, the database does that for you) over sets (of rows), but never over tuples.

Comment: Yes that is correct.