# Looking for a nice way to split

Tags: split

I'm trying to split a List at a splitting point in Scala.

For Example, splitting the following List:

`List(2,6,4,7,9,10)` with a splitting point of 4

would result in:

```
result: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 6, 4, 7), List(9, 10))
```

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use any. I'd just prefer minimal use of the standard library

Comment: So you're essentially writing C code with just enough Scala syntax to make it confusing.

Comment: @jwvh To be fair, the actual implementation of `splitAt` looks an awful lot like C code!

Comment: I may understand not using built-in functions if this was some kind of assignment to learn about recursion. Otherwise I really do not understand what is the point of not using the stdlib?

Comment: @Tim My point exactly!

Answer (score 1):

This is a functional version for your `split` function:

```
def split[A](ls: List[A], n: Int): List[List[A]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[A], take: Int, taken: List[A]): List[List[A]] =
    rem match {
      case hd :: tail if take > 0 =>
        loop(tail, take - 1, hd +: taken)
      case _ =>
        List(taken.reverse, rem)
    }

  loop(ls, n, Nil)
}
```

The actual implementation of `splitAt` uses non-functional techniques like mutable values and a `while` loop.

Note that there is still a lot of library code, as `List` is a library class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any buit-in functions, you may at least take a look at the source code. In your case, you should check `.splitAt(...)` function and slightly adapt it

```
def split(l: List[Int], n: Int) = {
  val b = new ListBuffer[Int]
  var i = 0
  var these = l
  while (!these.isEmpty && i < n) {
    i += 1
    b += these.head
    these = these.tail
  }
  (b.toList, these)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`splitAt`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L503), which according to the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOnceOps.html#splitAt(n:Int):(C,C)):

> Splits this collection into a prefix/suffix pair at a given position.
>
> Note: c splitAt n is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than) (c take n, c drop n).
>
> Note: might return different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered.

Therefore you can do:

```
List(2,6,4,7,9,10).splitAt(4)
```

Please note that this returns a tuple. If you want to convert it to list, you can read [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12392409/2359227)

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Tp4r5zyKRUmUhIbub5x9wg)